# Minimum requirements (especially screen size) for QGIs - Android

Tags: qgis, android, mobile

I would like to try Qgis on Android devices, but before, I would like to know the minimum terminals requirements, and especially the screen size or resolution, what is the minimum screen size do you recommends? At least to don't have any trouble to use it (I tried it on my smartphone... but some menu where larger than the screen size, so I had to stop my smartphone)!
At the same time, if some people have already used it, do not hesitate to give more requirement (memory, cpu, etc.).

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

have a look at http://hub.qgis.org/wiki/20/Tested_Devices
Basically, I suggest to get at least 7-8" that will allow 1280 x 800. The reference device is A Galaxy note 3 (because I own one)

Answer (score 0):

On the link provided the Samsung Galaxy Note 8 is listed.
I attempted since October to install the nightly build and failed.  There were several methods I tried I installed Ministro, Ministro II, did it as root etc.
Then I just stumbled across a comment that the "external" sd card needed to be dismounted.
Dismounted my 64GB SD card and it worked.

The screen size (8") is just a tad to small, the status bar is cut approximately in half height wise.  Thus when it is supposed to be showing a scale of 8364 the map canvas covers just above where the middle horizontal stroke is in the "3".